# Subquery returns more than one row, any doesn't help

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
select first_name, middle_name, last_name 
from students 
where student_id = any (select student_id 
                        from entries 
                        where subject_id = (select subject_id 
                                           from subjects 
                                            where exam_board = "OCR"));
```

Subquery returns more than one row. I feel sure I'm missing something obvious, but if anyone has an answer I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: Change = to IN? select first_name, middle_name, last_name from students where student_id IN (select student_id from entries where subject_id IN (select subject_id from subjects where exam_board = "OCR"));

Comment: Notice you have more than one subquery.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting multiple values to be returned from a sub query, you need to use an `IN` statement:

```
select first_name, middle_name, last_name 
from students 
where student_id IN (select student_id 
                        from entries 
                        where subject_id IN (select subject_id 
                                           from subjects 
                                            where exam_board = "OCR"));
```

However, looking at the data provided, you can actually join these tables together

```
select first_name, middle_name, last_name
from   students inner join
       entries on students.student_id = entries.student_id inner join
       subjects on entries.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
where  exam_board = "OCR";
```

Answer (score 0):

You subquery is returning student_id's from the entries table that have the subject_id equal to the subject_id associated with the exam_board, "OCR" from the subjects table.

Your subquery can and will return zero, one or more student_id values.
ANY will return true if student.student_id matches any of the student_id values (returned by your subquery) and the first_name, middle_name, last_name associated with that student_id will be returned.